# Regex egrep finding .gz but NOT .tar.gz

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, find

I need to find all `.gz` files but *not* `.tar.gz` files in a directory and then send all `.gz` files to `some_other_command` for processing.

I could get so far:

`find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/*\.gz$|[NOT .tar.gz]' -exec some_other_command -- '{}' '+'`

`some_other_command` needs only `.gz` files and *not* `.tar.gz`. What should my `[NOT .tar.gz]` part of regex be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
find . -name "*.gz" ! -name "*.tar.gz" -exec some_other_command -- '{}' '+'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       I want        I do not want
```

Answer (score 1):

With lookbehind from grep:

```
find . | grep -P '(?<!\.tar)\.gz' | xargs some_other_command
```